# String split function not returning desired output

Tags: java, split

I was expecting the `OUTPUT` to be `3` from the below class:

```
public class Pattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "111,577,5099,541,142,
                       2015-08-01 00:08:42,2015-08-01 06:31:52|
                       674,898,7061,36,105,2015-08-01 19:28:45,
                       2015-08-02 14:46:27|948,522,1840,66,889,
                       2015-08-02 13:04:56,2015-08-02 19:39:57";

        if(data.contains("|"))
        {
           String pattern[] = data.split("|");
           System.out.println("the pattern length:  "+pattern.length);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> the pattern length: 180

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character `|` is a special character in regexes (the `split` method uses regexes)

You'll have to go with

```
String pattern[] = data.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 1):

kindly update your code likewise,

```
 String pattern[] = data.split("\\|");
```